# How cache data from database and use it in Scoped class ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, singleton

I would like to cache date from one table, and return it when user do request to this table. I created class like this:

```
public interface ICategoryCache
{
    IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories();
}
public class CategoryCache : ICategoryCache
{
    private IEnumerable<Category> _categories;
    public CategoryCache(ItBuildsDbContext context)
    {
        _categories = context.Category.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return _categories;
    }
}
```

I wanted to add dependency injection as Singleton, but class which have to use this object is Scoped (and it throw error: Cannot consume scoped service). How should I do it properly? I am not able to change Scoped class to Singleton.

Should I for example create Factory which will create my Singleton object CategoryCache?

My solution for this problem which work:

```
public class CategoryCache
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Category> _categories;
    private static CategoryCache? _categoryCache;

    private CategoryCache(ItBuildsDbContext context)
    {
        _categories = context.Category.ToList();
    }

    public static CategoryCache Create(ItBuildsDbContext context)
    {
        if(_categoryCache == null)
        {
            _categoryCache = new CategoryCache(context);
        }

        return _categoryCache;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return _categories!;
    }
}

public interface IFactoryCategoryCache
{
    CategoryCache Create();
}

public class FactoryCategoryCache : IFactoryCategoryCache
{
    private readonly ItBuildsDbContext _context;
    public FactoryCategoryCache(ItBuildsDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public CategoryCache Create()
    {
        return CategoryCache.Create(_context);
    }
}


service.AddScoped<IFactoryCategoryCache, FactoryCategoryCache>();
```

But is there a better solution here?

Comment: You posted a badly worded question that hides an interesting/thorny time-related problem. End of day is a valid business concept but can't be represented in most programming languages. Flight schedules *are* posted as `24:00` instead of `00:00` of the next day for example. If you have an End-of-Day question make that explicit. SOAP does allow `24:00` as a valid time. With `System.DateTime` and even NodaTime though the solution is to handle End-of-Day as a special value that's `00:00` of the next day. There are several similar questions

Answer (score 2):

You are maybe doing something wrong, because it is possible to inject a singleton in a scoped service.

Example:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryCache>(new CategoryCache(new List<string> { "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3" }));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ScopedTestService>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

```
    public interface ICategoryCache
    {
        IEnumerable<string> GetCategories();
    }

    public class CategoryCache : ICategoryCache
    {
        private IEnumerable<string> _categories;
        public CategoryCache(IEnumerable<string> context)
        {
            _categories = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetCategories()
        {
            return _categories;
        }
    }
```

```
public class ScopedTestService
{
    private readonly ICategoryCache _categoryCache;

    public ScopedTestService(ICategoryCache categoryCache)
    {
        _categoryCache = categoryCache;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetCategories()
    {
        return _categoryCache.GetCategories();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried add dependency by:
service.AddSingleton<ICategoryCache, CategoryCache>(); How can I get object ItBuildsDbContext if for me it is database. I adding it in this way service.AddDbContext<ItBuildsDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ItBuildsDbConnection"))); And I can't create new instance for this object

Comment: Since you are creating ItBuildsDbContext and CategoryCache as a service and you are also asking for an ItBuildsDbContext object in the CategoryCache constructor, everything should work just fine… 
Maybe something goes wrong with the ItBuildsDbContext class.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the default lifetime of the dbcontext is Scoped,and you injected it to the Singleton Service

[image]

If you just cache date from one table and don't modify the data at any time,you could set as below:

```
services.AddDbContext<ServicelifetimeContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(".....")), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

**Update:**

You may try with DbContextFactory for your requirement

in startup:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ServicelifetimeContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServicelifetimeContext")));
```

in different services:

```
public CategoryCache(IDbContextFactory<ServicelifetimeContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _mymodels = contextFactory.CreateDbContext().Mymodel.ToList();
        }
```

I tried in a MVC project:

```
public MymodelsController(IDbContextFactory<ServicelifetimeContext> contextFactory,  ICategoryCache categoryCache)
        {
            _context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            _categoryCache = categoryCache;
        }

        // GET: Mymodels
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_categoryCache.GetMymodels());
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var mymodel = await _context.Mymodel.FindAsync(id);
            if (mymodel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(mymodel);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Now you could get the context with different lifetime

Comment: But I cache data only for one table, in another place I whenever take data from the database.

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it